# Drop rows in a dataframe where first column is a weekend date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a `Dataframe` that looks like (e.g.) this:

```
print(df)

           date     high      low   close
0    2008-01-01   15.540   15.540   15.54
1    2008-01-02   15.750   15.210   15.25
2    2008-01-03   15.450   14.950   15.02
3    2008-01-04   14.990   14.400   14.48
4    2008-01-05   14.890   14.400   14.78
5    2008-01-06   14.890   14.400   14.78
....
```

I would like to remove the rows from the `Dataframe` whose date column contains a weekend date.

```
           date     high      low   close
0    2008-01-01   15.540   15.540   15.54
1    2008-01-02   15.750   15.210   15.25
2    2008-01-03   15.450   14.950   15.02
3    2008-01-04   14.990   14.400   14.48
4 <-- has been removed since 1/05/2008 is a Saturday   
5 <-- has been removed since 1/06/2008 is a Sunday
....
```

I tried this:

```
df = df[~df.date.dt.weekday_name.isin(['Saturday','Sunday']).any(0)]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need `any(0)`, just use `df[~df.date.dt.weekday_name.isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])]`. `any(0)` collapses to a single Boolean value (probably `True`), while you need a vector / array of Booleans.

Comment: Try this: `df = df[df.date.dt.weekday < 5]`

Comment: Duh, thanks jpp that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an exclusion list (in case you want to add other days) like so:

```
day_exclusion = ['Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

The code below converts the date column to a datetime dtype, which was only necessary given I used pd.read_clipboard() to recreate your dataframe (if your dtype is already a datatime you can remove the pd.to_datetime portion). Then it returns a dataframe with all days not in you exclusion list.

```
df[~(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.weekday_name.isin(day_exclusion))]
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "easier" approach would make use of [`dt.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) (0 monday, 6 sunday)

```
df = df[df.date.dt.weekday < 5]
```

or:

```
df.query('date.dt.weekday < 5', inplace=True)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-01-07'),
    'name': [
        'Robert Baratheon',
        'Jon Snow',
        'Daenerys Targaryen',
        'Theon Greyjoy',
        'Tyrion Lannister',
        'Cersei Lannister',
        'Sansa Stark'
    ]
})

df = df[df.date.dt.weekday < 5]
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
        date                name
0 2019-01-01    Robert Baratheon
1 2019-01-02            Jon Snow
2 2019-01-03  Daenerys Targaryen
3 2019-01-04       Theon Greyjoy
6 2019-01-07         Sansa Stark
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code work perfectly.

It will remove "Saturday" and "Sunday" records from dataframe

```
        # *********** Removing weekend data from dataframe. ***************
    df["weekday"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.dayofweek
    no_weekend_data = df.drop(df.loc[df["weekday"] > 4].index)
```